# ObjectMapper (serialization) through protocol & extension

Tags: ios, swift, serialization, protocols

I'm building a library that provides user data from a server, but I don't want to define a concrete class, because I want the end user to be able to specify any parent class they want (eg: `NSManagedObject`). I also would like to provide mapping functionality through the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library.

My current thought is to write a protocol named `User` that has all of the variables and parent protocols declared and use an extension on the protocol to add the mapping and network functionality.

Here is my first attempt:

```
protocol GenericUser: Mappable {

    var name: String { get set }
    var email: String { get set }
}

extension GenericUser {

    mutating func dynamicMapping(map: Map) {

        name <- map["name"]
        email <- map["email"]
    }
}

class AppSpecificUser: NSManagedObject, GenericUser {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var email: String
    @NSManaged var uid: String

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {

        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        dynamicMapping(map)
        uid <- map["generic_bag"]["uid"]
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I cannot call a `mutating` function from a static context (self is immutable). However, I cannot manipulate the name and email properties if I don't specify the `dynamicMapping()` function as `mutating`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar dilemma though I am using Realm.  Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @damianesteban I've ended up building my own extension to `AlamofireObjectMapper` to support core data through child contexts so that I could do it from a base class. I'm hoping to refine it and submit a PR, or at least a fork.